# transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android

I've got this problem and I tried all the solutions available here an over the internet, but non of them worked for me. Adding multiDexEnabled true, adding multidex in gradle and extending my application from MultiDexApplication and ...
So please dont mark it duplicated, maybe someone could help. Thanks.

This is the stacktrace log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar,     
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, 
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatterDevs\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I had some external dependencies that were also imported internally (with different versions). Removing duplicated imports fixed the issue for me. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you add an external library which may not be compatible with your compileSdkVersion .

Be careful when you are adding an external library.

Make sure all your support libraries are same as compileSdkVersion of your build.gradle(Module:app) in my case it is 26.

In your defaultConfig category type multiDexEnabled true. This is the important part. multiDexEnabled True

Go to **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Instant Run and try to Enable/Disable Instant Run** to hot swap... and click okay Enable Instant Run to Hot swap...

**Sync Your project.**

**Lastly, Go to Build | click on Rebuild Project.**

Note: **Rebuild Project first cleans and then builds the project.**